# How can I centralize kable tables in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, kable

I'm writing a document in RMarkdown using `bookdown::pdf_document2`. I'm using `kableExtra` package to generate tables.

This is the code:

```
library(kableExtra)

data.frame(exp = c("LR Test", "R$^2$ de McFadden"),
                     value = c("4155.8$^{***}$", 0.299)) |>
  kable(col.names = c("Variável explicativa", "Efeito"),
        caption = "Teste de razão de verossimilhança",
        booktabs = TRUE,
        longtable = TRUE,
        linesep = "",
        escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling(position = "center") |>
  footnote(general_title = "",
           general = "Nota: $^{*}$p $<$ 0.1; $^{**}$p $<$ 0.05; $^{***}$p $<$ 0.01",
           escape = FALSE)
```

I'm already using `kable_styling(position = "center")` to positioning the table in center of the page, but this is the result that i'm getting:

[image]

How can I position the table in center of the page?

Comment: It's centered when I run it on my machine. Perhaps try updating your packages, R and RStudio, and LaTeX? Also, your output doesn't look very much like a LaTeX document – are you sure this is not html or rtf?

Comment: It's LaTex, I made a lot of changes to the text style. And everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, just the complete Rmd file that I used. Perhaps see what happens if you compile it yourself?

````
---
title: "Centered Table"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

## R Markdown

Some text.

```{r}
library(kableExtra)

data.frame(exp = c("LR Test", "R$^2$ de McFadden"),
                     value = c("4155.8$^{***}$", 0.299)) |>
  kable(col.names = c("Variável explicativa", "Efeito"),
        caption = "Teste de razão de verossimilhança",
        booktabs = TRUE,
        longtable = TRUE,
        linesep = "",
        escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling(position = "center") |>
  footnote(general_title = "",
           general = "Nota: $^{*}$p $<$ 0.1; $^{**}$p $<$ 0.05; $^{***}$p $<$ 0.01",
           escape = FALSE)
```
````

Output looks like this:
[image: screenshot]
And this is the tex code of the table:

```latex
\begin{longtable}[t]{ll}
\caption{\label{tab:unnamed-chunk-1}Teste de razão de verossimilhança}\\
\toprule
Variável explicativa & Efeito\\
\midrule
LR Test & 4155.8$^{***}$\\
R$^2$ de McFadden & 0.299\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}Nota: $^{*}$p $<$ 0.1; $^{**}$p $<$ 0.05; $^{***}$p $<$ 0.01}\\
\end{longtable}
```

Perhaps this will help with your troubleshooting.

Comment: When I run rmd with just the table, it centers exactly like in your example. But when I put it in my document, it doesn't work. I'm thinking maybe it's some setting in my document. Thank you for your help!